# Which one is correct: "the total miles is 275" or "the total miles are 275"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Can you please tell me if I have to say *the total miles is 275* or *the total miles are 275*? For example:

> The load needs to be delivered to Austin, TX, which is 250 loaded miles. The total miles **is**/**are** 275.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.  "The total *distance* is 275 miles."

Why? Because a mile is a unit to measure distance.  You don't say "The kilograms are 5"; you say "the weight* is 5 kilograms".  Similarly you don't say "The miles are 275"; you say "The distance is 275 miles".

---

<sup>* or "mass"</sup>

Comment: I wish I could give you a million upvotes just for the footnote...one of my bugbears, thank you!